# Freezing autoincrement temporary

Tags: google-sheets

I want to do something like this, where I've serial number, that is getting freeze if the column B ticked as true, and be continued after that

[image: ![enter image description here]

That is if I checked the `checkbox` beside number 3, it became 2, i.e. autoincrement freezed at the number before it, when I checked the `checkbx` under it, autocanting steel freeze, so number 2 also aappeared, after that the checkbox is unchecked, so autonumbering resumed after 2 and continued from 3, and so on

I tried doing:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(H2:H)=0,,if(F2:F=true,offset(indirect(address(row(),column())),row()-1,0,1,1)+1,offset(indirect(address(row(),column())),-1,0,1,1))))
```

But got an error:

> Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation,
> see File > Spreadsheet Settings.

Also tried this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B=false,INDIRECT("a"&row(A1:A))+1,INDIRECT("a"&row()-1,true)))
```

But did not work and gave:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "And be continued after that"?

Comment: @Aerials As you see in the screen shot attached, if I checked the `checkbox` beside number 3, it became 2, i.e. autoincrement freezed at the number before it, when I checked the `checkbx` under it, autocanting steel freeze, so number 2 also aappeared, after that the checkbox is unchecked, so autonumbering resumed after 2 and continued from 3, and so on, hope thiss make it more clear, thanks for your support.

Comment: Do you want this to be `ARRAYFORMULA`, or dragging down from the first cell would also be appropriate? Also, would you be open to using an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)?

Comment: @Iamblichus thanks for yourr interest to support, actually I do not want the user to do anything like `copy/pate` or `dragging down`, so I thought `arrayformula` could be the best, as I write it for the user, then lock the cloumn so he can not distroy it by mistake, if I can do so with `custom function` I'm open for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using an Apps Script custom function:

- Retrieve range `B2:B` as [argument](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments).
- Transform the 2D array to simple array and filter out empty cells, using [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- For each checkbox, count the number of `false` values in the array until that index, using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
function autoIncrement(checkboxes) {
  checkboxes = checkboxes.flat().filter(String);
  const count = checkboxes.map((val,i) => {
    return [checkboxes.slice(0,i+1).filter(check => !check).length];
  })
  return count;
}
```

[image]

#### Dragging down formula:

- Use [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en) and [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) to get the range until the current row.
- Use [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) to get the number of `false` values up until that row.
- Write formula in cell `A2` and drag down.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B2:B"&ROW()),false)
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the `customs function` I tried relacing the `return count` by `let requestRef = new Array()
  count.forEach(function(element) {
    if (parseInt(element) < 10) {requestRef.push('PRF.SC21.DNP.00'&element)}
    else if (parseInt(element)) {requestRef.push('PRF.SC21.DNP.0'&element)}
    else requestRef.push('PRF.SC21.DNP.'&element)
  });  
  return requestRef;` but I got it returning array of `0` only, any thought?

Comment: @HasanAYousef I guess you want to preppend these strings before the numbers, and return for example, `PRF.SC21.DNP.002`. [&](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND) is not the way to do that. You can do this instead: `"PRF.SC21.DNP.00" + element`, or `\`PRF.SC21.DNP.00${element}\`` ([template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is fine now.